# Unity 'Collider.bounds.Intersects'. Does it handle rotation?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

You will probably laugh at my code here (and I would love to hear some completely different approaches to this problem if possible), but I've written this myself using the only logic I could come up with alone.

Basically I want to make a slope randomly covered with trees. The slope is a quad with a mesh collider (I've also tried Box), and the tree is a prefab with just a model and a collider.  I iterate through every possible tree location and give it a 0.25 chance of spawning a tree. This all works ok, but since the quad is not lying flat to any axis, I couldn't think how best to assign the Y-position value to my trees.

My idea was to simply drop the trees all from above and have them land in the quads collider. If I lay the quad flat my code will work fine, but as soon as I tilt the slope the collision is still detected. It seems as if its reading the top of the quads highest point and making a box around it all the way to the bottom.

This is the code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < trees.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!trees[i].GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.Intersects(ski_slope.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds))
            {
                Debug.Log("moving tree");
                trees[i].transform.Translate(0, -0.2f, 0);

            }
        }
```

So really I think my use of the 'Intersects' function must be wrong.

I hope my description of the problem makes sense. Otherwise I can take some screenshots to try show it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those many situations where reading the documentation helps.

[The documentation for the Bounds type](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) tells you that it:

> Represents an axis aligned bounding box.
>
> An axis-aligned bounding box, or AABB for short, is a box aligned with coordinate axes and fully enclosing some object. Because the box is **never rotated** with respect to the axes, it can be defined by just its center and extents, or alternatively by min and max points.

[The documentation for Collider.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html) tells you it's:

> The **world space** bounding volume of the collider (Read Only).
>
> Note that this will be an empty bounding box if the collider is disabled or the game object is inactive.

So when you say:

> It seems as if its reading the top of the quads highest point and making a box around it all the way to the bottom.

Yes, that is *exactly* what you asked it to do. Asking for `Collider.bounds` says "find the highest, lowest, northmost, eastmost, southmost, and westmost points of this collider and give me a box aligned with the world axes enclosing those extremes".

Did you mean to use a raycast, spherecast, or boxcast sweeping downward to find the first intersection point with your mesh collider instead?

Comment: Thank you so much.... Much regret not studying the docs first :] You are very helpful! I have used Raycast before but completely forgot about them LOL. This should work perfectly.